# How to know an Android looks whether upwards or downwards?

Tags: android, sensors, portrait

I'm now creating AR application for Android, but a problem was happened.
By my implementation, a sensor show a same pitch even though the Android looks upwards or downwards.
Following picture shows what I want to say.

[image: what_I_want_to_say]

The sensor shows that pitch == -90 if I grab Android horizontally.
The problem is that I cannot detect a != b.(The sensor says a == b.)
Can anyone knows how to know an Android looks upwards or downwards?
The orientation of Android must be portrait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` is used for that case.

## Position Sensors

The Android platform provides two sensors that let you determine the position of a device: the geomagnetic field sensor and the orientation sensor. The Android platform also provides a sensor that lets you determine how close the face of a device is to an object (known as the proximity sensor).

The orientation data as follows,

```
resultingAngles[1] = orientationData[0]; // orientation z axis to y axis
resultingAngles[2] = orientationData[1]; // orientation x axis to z axis 
resultingAngles[0] = orientationData[2]; // orientation y axis to x axis
```

You have done rotation in y z x manner. Try to change the orientation..

Please refer the documentation for the event values,
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html